# Use checkboxes to add cell information to a list in a different column

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, filter, checkbox, google-sheets-formula

I have a master list of account codes used by my employer on a DatVal sheet for a budget tracker I used. I want to use checkboxes to select the most relevant codes to include in a list in a separate column that will become a data validated drop down list on another sheet.

I'm trying to use lookup and it sort of works, but is broken. I'm looking to see if the checkbox column is marked "True" then returning the result from a column where I've joined the account code and its description.

[Here is an image of the sheet.][image: 1]

I've set up an example sheet here: (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fxIfqjBjqTLMLRlyYAEy1j1aUn8vxyVwqgOKNpZoeZg/edit?usp=sharing)

And a table:

| Relevant Account Codes | Include in list | Common Account Codes | Account Code Descriptions | Joined |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Category 1 |  |  |  |
| 60017 - generic data 17 | FALSE | 60001 | generic data 1 | 60001 - generic data 1 |
|  | FALSE | 60002 | generic data 2 | 60002 - generic data 2 |
|  | TRUE | 60003 | generic data 3 | 60003 - generic data 3 |
|  | Category 2 |  |  | - |
|  | TRUE | 60004 | generic data 4 | 60004 - generic data 4 |
|  | TRUE | 60005 | generic data 5 | 60005 - generic data 5 |
|  | FALSE | 60006 | generic data 6 | 60006 - generic data 6 |
|  | TRUE | 60007 | generic data 7 | 60007 - generic data 7 |
| 60009 - generic data 9 | TRUE | 60008 | generic data 8 | 60008 - generic data 8 |
|  | TRUE | 60009 | generic data 9 | 60009 - generic data 9 |
|  | FALSE | 60010 | generic data 10 | 60010 - generic data 10 |
|  | FALSE | 60011 | generic data 11 | 60011 - generic data 11 |
|  | FALSE | 60012 | generic data 12 | 60012 - generic data 12 |
|  | FALSE | 60013 | generic data 13 | 60013 - generic data 13 |
|  | TRUE | 60014 | generic data 14 | 60014 - generic data 14 |
|  | Category 3 |  |  | - |
|  | FALSE | 60015 | generic data 15 | 60015 - generic data 15 |
|  | FALSE | 60016 | generic data 16 | 60016 - generic data 16 |
|  | FALSE | 60017 | generic data 17 | 60017 - generic data 17 |

This is my first post on stackoverflow. Long time lurker. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks, I'm a pretty basic user of spreadsheets.

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: What's the input and what's the expected result for the given input? Could you clarify which range in the screenshot and the table is input and output?

Comment: Thanks for your help.

The input in the checkbox. It should output the joined data (account code "-" account description) to a list in column A.

Basically, I want to check a box and have the information added to a list in a separate column so I can use that in a datval list for data entry.

Comment: Not getting you. If Column A is the expected result, explain why `A3` is `60017 - generic data 17`. Or is `E:E` the expected result?

Comment: It's not. That's my broken formula returning the incorrect data. I should have explained that, my apologies.

What I need it to do is as @player0 showed. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: No worries. In the future, try to recreate the output that you want manually and add it as a table to your question.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the helpful comments about formatting et al.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B3:B=TRUE, E3:E, ))
```

[image]

or skip the blanks like:

```
=FILTER(E3:E, B3:B=TRUE)
```